# Entity framework generated type in request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to use entity framework auto generated type like property in post request?

If i will send this json,

```
"{"Type":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"ShankType":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"SharpeningAngel":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"SharpeningDirection":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"MaterialFor":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"WorkingLength":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"Length":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"},"Diameter":{"CharacteristicId":"test1","CommodityId":"test2"}}"
```

to `SaveDrill` method. It would not work because `CommoditiesCharacteristics` not suitable. I tried to decorate properties with `BindNeverAttribute`

```
[BindNever]
public int Id { get; set; }
[BindNever]
public virtual DrillBitsCharacteristics Characteristic { get; set; }
[BindNever]
public virtual Commodities Commodity { get; set; }
```

But without success. Is it possible to decorate somehow properties in `CommoditiesCharacteristics` to make it workable. Or in this case only one way it is to make new type?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SaveDrill")]
public IActionResult SaveDrill(Drill drill)
{
    _toolStoreContext.CommoditiesCharacteristics.Add(drill.Type);
    _toolStoreContext.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}

public class Drill
{
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics Type { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics ShankType { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics SharpeningAngel { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics SharpeningDirection { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics MaterialFor { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics WorkingLength { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics Length { get; set; }
    public CommoditiesCharacteristics Diameter { get; set; }
}

public partial class CommoditiesCharacteristics
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CharacteristicId { get; set; }
    public int CommodityId { get; set; }
    public virtual DrillBitsCharacteristics Characteristic { get; set; }
    public virtual Commodities Commodity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue I see is, `CharacteristicId is Int` in model, but you pass a string in JSON.

```
"CharacteristicId":"test1"
```

CommodityId is the same.

Otherwise it must work. Null values will be assigned when some property is null in json.